# Glassfish won't start in debug mode on windows

Tags: java, glassfish, payara

`asadmin start-domain --debug=true`

JDK: `jdk1.8.0_172`
Payara: `4.1.2.181`

produces the following output.

```
Waiting for domain1 to start ..Error starting domain domain1.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 2.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]

Command start-domain failed.
```

The glassfish log file only contains this:
There are no additional clues as to why it cannot start in debug mode.

`asadmin start-domain` works just perfectly.

```
[2018-05-15T14:43:27.424+0200] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [javax.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1526388207424] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe
-cp
C:/Java/payara41/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=n,suspend=y
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:C:/Java/payara41/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-client
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish/modules/endorsed;C:\Java\payara41\glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Djava.security.policy=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dorg.glassfish.grizzly.DEFAULT_MEMORY_MANAGER=org.glassfish.grizzly.memory.HeapMemoryManager
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Dorg.jboss.weld.serialization.beanIdentifierIndexOptimization=false
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172/jre/lib/ext;C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Djava.library.path=C:/Java/payara41/glassfish/lib;C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;C:/Utilities;C:/Program Files/Common Files/microsoft shared/Microsoft Online Services;C:/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/microsoft shared/Microsoft Online Services;C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin;C:/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon;C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin;C:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4;C:/Users/QXV0615/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps;C:/Program Files/PortableGit/cmd;C:/Users/QXV0615/AppData/Local/hyper/app-2.0.0/resources/bin;C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code;C:/Java/payara41/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_172/bin;C:/Java/apache-maven-3.5.3/bin;C:/Users/QXV0615/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd;C:/Bin;C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/10/bin;C:/Projects/mcp/mcp
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
C:/Java/payara41/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=true,,,--domaindir,,,C:\Java\payara41\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
C:/Java/payara41/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
true
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain
-watchdog
false]]
```

*any tips on how I should resolve this?*

### edit

I have discovered that the `domain.xml` configuration files for debug startup were different between my version 172 and 181 are different.

174:

```
  <java-config classpath-suffix="" debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=n,suspend=y" java-home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" system-classpath="">
```

181:

```
 <java-config classpath-suffix="" debug-options="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=9009,server=n,suspend=y" java-home="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172" system-classpath="">
```

The `server`, `suspend` and `java-home` are different. The JDK path in the configuration file is correct.

They now both start, *but why?*

Comment: don't know what `--debug` does, but should you also specify something along the lines of `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=n`?

Comment: @Eugene that is what --debug does, with the debug port set to 9009 by default.

Comment: @Jim the java-config you have given for 174 and 181 are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like the ports used by Payara are already in use. The most likely reason for that is you already have a running instance of Payara which you haven't stopped.

You check what ports are in use by running `netstat -ano`.

Also, ensure that the startup options in `domain.xml` are correct. Some IDE's like *Intelij Idea* might change the options for local debugging - which break remote debugging. The options need to be restored.

Comment: this is a spectacularly interesting startup problem.
payara 4.1.2.181 does not start, payara 4.1.2.172 does.
what parameter might have changed between the two - I am still figuring it out with a diff, but i haven't found anything yet.

its' not just the port, unless that changed - but it doesn't seem to have.

Comment: I have updated the question, with more detail.
Perhaps if you have some experience with the debugging - you can attempt to provide some further information, I still want to know what exactly is incorrect.